# Need help troubleshooting what keeps crashing

Tags: crash, 21.10

Ubuntu 21.10 desktop, AMD Ryzen 5 3600 (3.6 GHz), 64 GB RAM

I'm having this problem both with Wayland and without.

Common to all crash situations is Firefox (default Snap install). Sometimes just Firefox will crash, but sometimes takes my entire system down with it. Sometimes I get the Firefox crash report screen, sometimes I wind up at the Ubuntu login screen, sometimes the system just freezes to the point that only a hard reset works.

I've found the "about:crashes" page in Firefox and just discovered that the last 2 weeks or so of crash reports weren't submitted, so I've now submitted all of those.

When I look at /var/log/syslog, I see far too much that I don't understand, but will happily post if someone can tell me what to look for.

Thanks in advance.

Edits below as requested. No overclocking on CPU or RAM.

ls -al /var/crash

```
total 12
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie 4096 Dec 16 07:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root     4096 Dec 15 20:32 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 robert   whoopsie    0 Dec 14 06:46 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie   37 Dec 14 06:46 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.uploaded
```

sudo lshw -C memory

```
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P1.70
       date: 12/01/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: f
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 64GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-16GVK
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-16GVK
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-16GVK
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-16GVK
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 12
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 13
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 14
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 32MiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

free -h

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62Gi       5.6Gi       1.2Gi       179Mi        55Gi        56Gi
Swap:           71Gi        17Mi        71Gi
```

swapon -s

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sdb1            partition  75497468    17536   -2
```

UPDATED 2021-12-19

ls -al /var/crash

```
total 3204
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie    4096 Dec 19 12:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root        4096 Dec 19 12:38 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 robert   whoopsie       0 Dec 19 12:41 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Dec 19 12:41 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 robert   whoopsie       0 Dec 19 12:41 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Dec 19 12:41 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 robert   whoopsie 3254690 Dec 19 12:41 _usr_bin_Xwayland.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 robert   whoopsie       0 Dec 19 12:41 _usr_bin_Xwayland.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Dec 19 12:41 _usr_bin_Xwayland.1000.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 robert   whoopsie       0 Dec 14 06:46 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Dec 14 06:46 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.uploaded
```

ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 robert robert 4096 Dec 13 11:52 .
drwx------ 4 robert robert 4096 Dec 19 16:19 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 robert robert 4096 Dec 14 06:47 date-menu-formatter@marcinjakubowski.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 robert robert 4096 Dec  3 08:19 sensory-perception@HarlemSquirrel.github.io
```

ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 14  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Oct 16 19:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 16 18:49 ding@rastersoft.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 16 18:49 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 16 18:50 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `free -h`. Is your CPU or RAM overclocked?

Comment: Firefox installed with `apt` crashes too ?

Comment: I have not tried switching back to the apt version. I saw some guides for switching and it seems like a headache that I would be fighting upstream against with every upgrade.

Comment: @heynnema, edits posted! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the data! Why such a large swap? Do you hibernate? Please show me `swapon -s` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your motherboard. Thanks!

Comment: Don't run `memtest` yet, as it'll take a long time for 64G RAM. I'll have you run it overnight, or when you're not using the computer. Just get the `memtest` download for now to prepare. Build the flash drive. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete.

Comment: @heynnema swapon -s added to question, motherboard info below:

ASRock B550M Pro4, chipset: AMD B550, BIOS: American Megatrends P1.70

I last ran memtest86+ on 2/4/2021 if that helps (I normally run it annually). Swap file is configured for hibernation, but I do not normally use hibernation.

Comment: Please see my initial answer. If it helps to solve the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I haven't been able to be on my PC extensively, but when I have been, I have had no problems. I've even gone back to the dark theme and re-enabled the Date Menu Formatter extension with no crashes, so I think we can say that changing the video driver from nouveau to Nvidia fixed it! Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

ASRock B550M Pro4

You have an older BIOS version 1.70 from 12/10/20, and there's a newer BIOS available, version 2.20 from 8/5/21, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B550M%20Pro4/index.asp#BIOS).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model motherboard.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**vm.swappiness**

With 64G RAM, you can reduce swapping, and speed up operations, by adjusting vm.swappiness.

- edit /etc/sysctl.conf
- add **vm.swappiness=10** (at the end of the file)
- sudo sysctl -p (or reboot)

**Memtest** (do this after the BIOS update)

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

**Firefox**

- Open `Ubuntu Software`
- Search for "Firefox"
- You'll find two listed, one snap version, and one standard .deb version...

Snap version details...

[image]

Standard .deb version details...

[image]

- You have the snap version installed
- **Remove** the snap version
- **Install** the standard .deb version
- Quit `Ubuntu Software`
- Start Firefox and retest for crashes

**Update #2:**

- We switched from using Wayland, to X11/xorg
- We removed all themes/icons and unnecessary extensions
- Remmina is now running fine
- Switched from Firefox SNAP, to standard .deb/repo Firefox
- Firefox appears to be stable now
- Updated Firefox to 95.0.1
- Switched from nouveau video driver to Nvidia 470

Comment: Okay, all of that is done. I hadn't upgraded the BIOS because the website said it was just for newer CPUs, but now I'm up to date. Memtest v. 9.3 run 4/4, passed with flying colors. In between the BIOS update and the Memtest, logged in to change the swappiness, and while I had Firefox open ... it crashed.

Comment: @KneadToKnow Give me a minute to write an update to my answer. When you see it, do it, retest Firefox, and report back...

Comment: @KneadToKnow If you've installed any themes on your computer, default back to the default theme.

Comment: @KneadToKnow Status please...

Comment: Snap Firefox removed, deb Firefox installed, Dark Yaru theme and Icons reset to Adwaita. I did not change Cursor themes because I could not identify which was default, so still Yaru. I also disabled the Date Menu Formatter extension, which was the only one I could remember starting to use anytime recently. Will be testing Firefox over the next hour or so between holiday preparation responsibilities. Thank you again for your help with this!

Comment: Not quite an hour of testing yet, but I've not seen any full crashes. There have half a dozen or so instances where the system stopped responding for 5-15 seconds, but I've been very patient with it and it's stayed with me so far.

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that many if not most of these momentary freezes seem to be happening when I'm using Remmina to remotely work on another computer and roll the mouse pointer off the Remmina screen back to my local desktop.

Comment: Also, I see now I've got a bunch more things when I do ls -al /var/crash. I've updated the question with the new info.

Comment: @KneadToKnow Are you currently running Wayland or X11/xorg? Check Settings/About/Windowing System/. If it says Wayland, log out, at the login screen, select your username, then click on the icon in the lower-right corner of the screen, select "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu on X11/xorg", then enter your password. Recheck Settings/About/Windowing System and it should say X11. Test that for a while.

Comment: @KneadToKnow Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @KneadToKnow sensory-perception extension has some bad reviews. Try `Vitals` instead https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/

Comment: @KneadToKnow Were you running Wayland?

Comment: Sorry, system crashed while I was trying to check. I am on Wayland, as I said originally, I have been having crashes in both. Disabling sensory-perception and switching to xorg now, barring another crash. :)
EDIT
Turns out, sensory-perception was already disabled. Should I remove it altogether?

Comment: @KneadToKnow What crashed? Firefox? Something else? Look in /var/crash again. `ls -alt /var/crash`. You can replace sensory-perception with vitals, if you like. Switching to xorg may make the remmina pauses go away.

Comment: The entire system froze to the point that I had to hard reset. I don't see anything new in /var/crash, though. I'm afraid I'm done for tonight, but I'll be in and out of remmina tomorrow morning bright and early. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132464/discussion-between-heynnema-and-kneadtoknow).

Comment: I "up arrowed" your answer to nullify that needless down arrow someone dropped on it.

Comment: @KneadToKnow Thanks so much! Maybe even accept my answer?

Comment: Even though none of the steps used actually got us to the solution? I'm not trying to be dense or churlish, it just seems like that would be inaccurate.

Comment: @KneadToKnow Your choice, of course. The Dec 21st Update #2 in my answer documented the final fix to Nvidia, along with the prior fixes that we did together. Good for future readers to know what/how happened and how it ultimately got fixed :-)

Comment: Fair enough, and no problem. Still new here and learning how things are done.

Comment: @KneadToKnow Thanks again!